# what does it mean in blade @extends('some::thing')

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Today I have installed `jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte` and after following all the installation command I created a view and just wrote the line

```
@extends('adminlte::page')
```

and it works fine but I do not understand how it works? specially this `::` symbol? I checked the laravel documentation but could not find anything.

Please help me by explaining it or give some article/tutorial link from where I can learn more.

Comment: it is a hint path. I think it is used to load views from service providers.

Answer (score 5):

`adminlte` is the name of the package, which is used for `views` and `configs` in Laravel as a namespace in order to avoid conflicts with other other packages.

It is defined in the [ServiceProvider](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/blob/master/src/ServiceProvider.php#L51) class on line 51.

By calling this in your blade files:

```
@extends('adminlte::page')
```

you are telling to Laravel, that you want to extend the [page.blade.php](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/blob/master/resources/views/page.blade.php) file.

If you call `@extends('page')`, without `adminlte::`, it will look for the `page.blade.php` in your `resources/views` directory.

You won't see information in Laravel's Blade documentation section about this, because it's specific for Laravel Packages. And you can learn more from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/packages#views).

Answer (score -2):

```
::
```

symbol is a call of static function or static property in a class, for example if you define a class like this:

```
class Foo{
    public static $a = 1;
    public static function test(){}; 
}
```

you can use Foo::$a to get the value of $a, and use Foo::test() to call the function test().

Comment: Your explanation is ok, but it is not the case.